# .htaccess combine 2 RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a small question .htaccess perspective.

I urls from the old site which is composed as follows: `news- pecq_mur_quai_plateforme_bimodale_dechargement_inauguration_escaut.html`

these URLs become : `pecq_mur_quai_plateforme_bimodale_dechargement_inauguration_escaut`

I have to delete '**news-**' and '**.html**' of these urls .

I have combined two rules and I do not see how. Here's my start code .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news-(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove both perms from your url using a single rule, try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news-(.*?)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this redirect.